# How do I return to a certain place in my code

Tags: java

I'm making a school project about working with arrays and I would like to make a statement at the end which asks do you want to start from the beginning or choose a different case, but I don't know how to return to a certain point in my program.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Mas {
    private static int j;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a, b;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ievadiet masīva izmērus");
        a = in.nextInt();
        b = in.nextInt();

        int[][] Masivs = new int[a][b];

        System.out.println("Tālāk tiks ievadīti masīva dati");
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            System.out.println("Ievadiet rindas nr. " + (i + 1) + " elementus");
            for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
                Masivs[i][j] = in.nextInt();
        }
        int det = 0;
        if (a == b && a <= 3)
            System.out.println("Vai velaties aprekinat masiva determinantu?");
        String x;
        x = in.next();
        switch (x) {
        case "ja":
            if (a == 3)
                det = (Masivs[0][0] * Masivs[1][1] * Masivs[2][2])
                        + (Masivs[0][1] * Masivs[1][2] * Masivs[0][2])
                        + (Masivs[0][2] * Masivs[1][0] * Masivs[2][1])
                        - (Masivs[0][2] * Masivs[1][1] * Masivs[2][0])
                        + (Masivs[0][1] * Masivs[1][0] * Masivs[2][2])
                        + (Masivs[0][0] * Masivs[1][2] * Masivs[2][1]);
            if (a == 2)
                det = (Masivs[0][0] * Masivs[1][1])
                        - (Masivs[0][1] * Masivs[1][0]);
            if (a == 1)
                det = Masivs[0][0];
            System.out.println("masiva determinats ir " + det);
        }
        String z;
        System.out
                .println("Izvelaties darbibu(vid-videjas vertibas aprekinasana vai max-maximalas un minimalas vertibas atrasana)");
        z = in.next();
        switch (z) {
        case "vid":
            System.out
                    .println("Jus izvelejaties videjas vertibas aprekinasanu");
            double sk = 0,
            sum = 0;
            double vid = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < b; j++) {
                    sk += 1;
                    sum += Masivs[i][j];
                    vid = sum / sk;
                }
            System.out.println("masiva videja vertiba ir " + vid);
            break;

        case "Max":
            System.out
                    .println("Jus izvelejaties augstakas un zemakas vertibas aprekinasanu");
            int max = 0,
            min = 2147483647;
            for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < b; j++) {
                    if (max < Masivs[i][j])
                        max = Masivs[i][j];
                    if (min > Masivs[i][j])
                        min = Masivs[i][j];
                }
            System.out.println("Masiva augstaka vertiba ir " + max
                    + " un zemaka vertiba ir " + min);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well.. you could follow [OOP principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)..

Comment: Yes, but it looks like the OP is still working on functional principles. Walk before running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the repeating code in a loop, and inside the loop ask the user what to do and take action based on that response.

```
boolean keepGoing = true;
do {
    // ask the user questions
    // if or switch goes here; probably best to separate steps into methods
    // does the user want to keep going?
} while (keepGoing);
```

Answer (score 1):

> How do I return to a certain place in my code

Split your code into well defined methods, and call them whenever needed. That's it, try to modularize your code.

If you want to repeat an algorithm a certain amount of time, or "infinitely", use the `for` or/and `while` loops.